# In ChartJS how do you format the hover over label in a time series?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

So I would like to keep the 'Date' data type and am using a setup in Angular 8 where I am setting a multiple datasets with a series of a type labeled 'Cartesian'.  I am getting documentation from here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis.  But I am either not reading correctly or missing if you can set the 'hover label' to be different.  It blows up if I don't keep it in time yet I can set the X Axis with callbacks in my code like so:

```
    const dashInput = this.getDashboardInput();
    const daysDifference = (+dashInput.endDate.getTime() - +dashInput.startDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if (daysDifference >= 150 ) {
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'month';
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.displayFormats.month = 'MM/YY';
    } else if (daysDifference >= 60) {
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'week';
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.displayFormats.week = 'MM/DD/YY';
    } else {
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'day';
      this.enrollmentsAndCompletionsChartInUI.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.displayFormats.day = 'MM/DD/YY';
    }
```

But I am not seeing how you set this hover box property.  Any help would be appreciated as I may have just missed something simple in the documentation.

Currently the configuration settings of ChartJs scales are set like so.  However the component overrides the setting as shown above.

```
scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'time axis',
        type: 'time',
        time: { 
          unit: 'day', 
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'MM/DD/YY'
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Enrollments'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
```

[image]

**To be clear I would like to see the hover over match the formatting of the XAxis like 08/05/19**

Comment: Please share the chartjs scales confguration used for both x and y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this approach:

External (Custom) Tooltips
Custom tooltips allow you to hook into the tooltip rendering process so that you can render the tooltip in your own custom way. Generally this is used to create an HTML tooltip instead of an oncanvas one. You can enable custom tooltips in the global or chart configuration like so:

var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
            enabled: false,

```
        custom: function(tooltipModel) {
            // Tooltip Element
            var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
            }

            // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
            } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
            }

            // Set Text
            if (tooltipModel.body) {
                var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                    var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                    var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                    style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                    style += '; border-width: 2px';
                    var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                    innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            }

            // `this` will be the overall tooltip
            var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Display, position, and set styles for font
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
            tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
            tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
            tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
            tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

});

See here

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed.  Their documentation on my solution appeared to be missing three pieces though: tooltipEl.style.border = '2px solid red';
              tooltipEl.style.zIndex = '1';
              tooltipEl.style.background = 'white';.  Their code generates a transparent box.  But this is exactly what I needed, thanks.